# Using custom_url_rewrite in drupal for static files

Tags: php, drupal

I want to write a drupal module that serves static files, but I want it to serve them from the address www.mydomain.com/moduleName/fileName Where FileName could be anything (e.g. javascript/app.js or photos/imageA.jpg). I don't want to copy the files to that actual location if possible, ideally I want the module to just hotlink the two locations.

I tried using a menu with a callback that looks like
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();

```
$fileName = drupal_get_path('module', 'moduleName') . "/files";
for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
    $fileName = $fileName . "/" . $arg_list[$i];
}
if ($numargs == 0) {
    $fileName = drupal_get_path('module', 'moduleName') . "/files/index.html";
}

if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    header('Content-Type: ' . getFileMimeType($fileName));
    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($fileName));
    fclose($handle);
    echo $contents;
} else {
    drupal_json_output(array('exists' => file_exists($fileName), 'fileName' => $fileName));
}
drupal_exit();
```

Where getFileMimeType looks like

```
function rcsarooms_getFileMimeType($file) {
    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($extension == "html" || $extension == "md") {
        $type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    } else if ($extension == "css") {
        $type = "text/css";
    } else if ($extension == "js") {
        $type = "application/x-javascript";
    } else if ($extension == "json") {
        $type = "application/json";
    } else if ($extension == "ico") {
        $type = "image/x-icon";
    } else if ($extension == "png") {
        $type = "image/png";
    } else {
        $type = "charset=UTF-8";
        echo $extension;
        drupal_exit();
        return;
    }
    return $type;
}
```

but while this works fine for any text files it fails completely for any binary files (e.g. png, ico etc.)  I also don't like having to specify the mime-type like that.

The question is, can custom_url_rewrite do what I need to do and if so what should the custom url rewrite function have in it and where should it go?

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function custom_url_rewrite($op, $result, $path) {
    if (strpos($result, "data") === false) {
        if ($op == 'alias') {
            if (preg_match('|^' . drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule') . '/files/(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
                return 'myModule/' . $matches[1];
            }
        }

        if ($op == 'source') {
            if (preg_match('|^myModule/(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
                return drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule') . '/files/'.$matches[1];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this function on php.net which does work (although I'm still interested to know if anyone else has a better way of doing this)

```
function readfile_chunked( $filename) { 
    $chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024); // how many bytes per chunk 
    $buffer = ''; 
    $cnt = 0; 
    $handle = fopen( $filename, 'rb' ); 
    if ( $handle === false ) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    ob_end_clean(); //added to fix ZIP file corruption 
    ob_start(); //added to fix ZIP file corruption 
    header( 'Content-Type:' ); //added to fix file corruption 
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=7200'); //time in seconds. so cache for 2 hours
    while ( !feof( $handle ) ) { 
        $buffer = fread( $handle, $chunksize ); 
        echo $buffer; 
        ob_flush(); 
        flush(); 
    } 
    fclose( $handle );
}
```

Comment: You might try [`fpassthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) for a more concise solution, it always works for me. Just so you know, [`custom_url_rewrite()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite/5) was for Drupal 5 only which is why you weren't getting any joy using that.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I just wanted to let anyone else reading here that the above code is a little messy/repetitive. Here's a cleaned up version: http://gist.github.com/3189322

Comment: Thanks, always love a good refactor :) it's an old post, but the code is still in use.